# Cannot make the position of contact form relative to other section

Tags: javascript, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3, contact-form

[image]I created a contact form on my webpage using the code in http://www.prepbootstrap.com/bootstrap-template/contact-form. I have the following questions:

1. The form is responsive but spills over into the previous section. What do I prevent it from overlapping with the previous section? I put the code for the contact form in a section just like for other sections:
2. Is it alright if I do not download the entire package and just use the HTML? I have the other mandatory components and get a form without the icons that works for me.
3. How do I specify where the submitted information goes to?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Can't add the code in the question for some reason. This is the code:

    <section id="contact" class="contact-section" padding-top="20px">
      <div class="container-fluid">
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
         <div class="well well-sm">

Comment: indent code by 4 spaces :)

Comment: show us your webpage please...

Comment: I added a screenshot. The white panes you see above are the panels from the previous section that I closed.

Comment: need to be able to see the full code to diagnose - set up a jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I put the abridged code at http://jsfiddle.net/kurious/pj54ajkn/. This probably won't give you much idea because the JavaScript backend isn't there to display the boxes. Please let me know if this workable or I need to provide additional information.

Comment: are you able to provide a link to the actual site?